# material ui multiple classnames with same definition

Tags: javascript, css, styles, material-ui

In traditional CSS, the following is common for defining shared properties between classes:

```
.classA,.classB{
  background-color: black;
}
```

In Material UI, using theming, the above can be translated as the following:

```
styles = (theme)=>({
    classA:{
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    classB:{
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    },    
})
```

I was wondering if there is a particular syntax to remove the duplication in the material UI styled approach above, ie, can the two classes be defined simultaneously?, Something along the following (in pseudocode):

```
styles = (theme)=>({
    classA,classB:{
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    }, 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just set a base class for the color?

```
blackBg: {
  backgroundColor: 'black'
}
```

and then use the classnames package to attach multiple classnames to your element

```
import classNames from 'classnames'

...
  <div className={classNames(blackBg, myOtherClass)} />
...
```